# Material-UI NextJS Button Styling Issue

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui, next.js

i am having a problem getting the styling right on a couple of buttons in JS, it seems when i add a styling class via className that on first render the formatting works, but on subsequent refreshes it loses its styling. It is only happening on the two individual buttons i have. After troubleshooting for ages, i have found that everything works when i use SX instead of classNames, so if i do this then the refresh works. So in code below one button styles and remains styles, but the second one, refreshing my button class does not? Stumped at this point, i ran through forums and see a lot about NextJs needing some extra config in _document and _app to make it work, but i ran this in from the NextJs Material UI boiler plate from Git so dont think it could be that causing it.

Code:

```
import React from 'react'

import { AppBar, Toolbar, alpha } from "@mui/material";
import Button from '@mui/material/Button'
import ButtonBase from '@mui/material/ButtonBase';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import InputBase from '@mui/material/InputBase';
import SearchIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Search';
import AddIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Add';
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles'

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({

    button: {
        ...theme.typography.mainmenu,
        borderRadius: "40px",
        width: "230px",
        height: "130px",
        marginLeft: "30px",
        alignItem: "center",
        "&:hover": {
            backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary
        },
        [theme.breakpoints.down("sm")]: {
            width: '100% !important', // Overrides inline-style
            height: 100
        },
    },

}))
/*Image Button Styling Begins*/
const images = [
    {
        url: '/assets/breakfastMenu.jpg',
        title: 'Breakfast',
        width: '20%',
    },
    {
        url: '/assets/steak.jpg',
        title: 'Mains',
        width: '20%',
    },
    {
        url: '/assets/desserts.jpg',
        title: 'Desserts',
        width: '20%',
    },
];
const Image = styled('span')(({ theme }) => ({
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    color: theme.palette.common.primary,
}));

const ImageButton = styled(ButtonBase)(({ theme }) => ({
    position: 'relative',
    height: 150,
    [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
        width: '100% !important', // Overrides inline-style
        height: 100,
    },
    '&:hover, &.Mui-focusVisible': {
        zIndex: 1,
        '& .MuiImageBackdrop-root': {
            opacity: 0.15,
        },
        '& .MuiImageMarked-root': {
            opacity: 0,
        },
        '& .MuiTypography-root': {
            border: '4px solid currentColor',
        },
    },
}));

const ImageSrc = styled('span')({
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    backgroundSize: 'cover',
    backgroundPosition: 'center 40%',
});
const ImageBackdrop = styled('span')(({ theme }) => ({
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.common.black,
    opacity: 0.4,
    transition: theme.transitions.create('opacity'),
}));

const ImageMarked = styled('span')(({ theme }) => ({
    height: 3,
    width: 18,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.common.white,
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: -2,
    left: 'calc(50% - 9px)',
    transition: theme.transitions.create('opacity'),
}));
/*Image Button Styling Ends*/

const Search = styled('div')(({ theme }) => ({
    position: 'relative',
    borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius,
    backgroundColor: alpha(theme.palette.common.white, 0.15),
    '&:hover': {
        backgroundColor: alpha(theme.palette.common.white, 0.25),
    },
    marginLeft: 0,
    width: '100%',
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
        marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
        width: 'auto',
    },
}));

const SearchIconWrapper = styled('div')(({ theme }) => ({
    padding: theme.spacing(0, 2),
    height: '100%',
    position: 'absolute',
    pointerEvents: 'none',
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
}));

const StyledInputBase = styled(InputBase)(({ theme }) => ({
    color: 'inherit',
    '& .MuiInputBase-input': {
        padding: theme.spacing(1, 1, 1, 0),
        // vertical padding + font size from searchIcon
        paddingLeft: `calc(1em + ${theme.spacing(4)})`,
        transition: theme.transitions.create('width'),
        width: '100%',
        [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
            width: '12ch',
            '&:focus': {
                width: '20ch',
            },
        },
    },
}));


const Header = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (<React.Fragment>
        <AppBar position="sticky" className={classes.appBar}>
            <Toolbar disableGutters>

                {images.map((image) => (
                    <ImageButton
                        focusRipple
                        key={image.title}
                        style={{
                            width: image.width,
                        }}
                    >
                        <ImageSrc style={{
                            backgroundImage: `url(${image.url})`
                        }} />
                        <ImageBackdrop className="MuiImageBackdrop-root" />
                        <Image>
                            <Typography
                                component="span"
                                variant="subtitle1"
                                color="white"
                                fontWeight="bold"

                                sx={{
                                    position: 'relative',
                                    p: "7em",
                                    pt: "2em",
                                    pb: (theme) => `calc(${theme.spacing(1)} + 6px)`,
                                }}
                            >
                                {image.title}
                                <ImageMarked className="MuiImageMarked-root" />
                            </Typography>
                        </Image>
                    </ImageButton>
                ))}
                <Button size="large" variant="contained" color="secondary"
                    startIcon={<AddIcon />}
                    sx={{
                        borderRadius: "40px", borderRadius: "40px",
                        width: "230px",
                        height: "130px",
                        marginLeft: "30px",
                        alignItem: "center",
                    }} >Add A recipe</Button>
                <Button size="large" variant="contained" color="secondary" className={classes.button}>Meals for the Week</Button>
                <Search>
                    <SearchIconWrapper>
                        <SearchIcon />
                    </SearchIconWrapper>
                    <StyledInputBase
                        placeholder="Search…"
                        inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'search' }}
                    />
                </Search>
            </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>

    </React.Fragment >
    )
}

export default Header
```

[image: Header with working and broken button]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly, you need to add some configuration to the `_document.tsx` in order to make the styles work properly with the NextJS server side rendering feature. The reason behind this is that you need that some styles are injected in the DOM for you.

As you can see in the MUI docs, you can use the [ServerStyleSheets](https://mui.com/styles/api/#serverstylesheets) to handle the server side rendering properly.

This is the code I have in my `_document.tsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import Document, { Html, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';
import { ServerStyleSheets } from '@mui/styles';


export default class MyDocument extends Document {
    render() {
        return (
            <Html>
                <body>
                    <Main />
                    <NextScript />
                </body>
            </Html>
        );
    }
}

MyDocument.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
    // Render app and page and get the context of the page with collected side effects.
    const sheets = new ServerStyleSheets();
    const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;

    ctx.renderPage = () =>
        originalRenderPage({
            enhanceApp: (App) => (props) => sheets.collect(<App {...props} />)
        });

    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);

    return {
        ...initialProps,
        // Styles fragment is rendered after the app and page rendering finish.
        styles: [...React.Children.toArray(initialProps.styles), sheets.getStyleElement()]
    };
};
```

You can read more information about this in these [Server rendering - MUI docs](https://mui.com/guides/server-rendering/#mui-on-the-server)